# Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4 Not Validating App for App Store Distribution

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I released version 1.1 of my app onto the App Store last week, and now have had to produce 1.1.1 very quickly. Last week, I was running XCode 4.3(.1, maybe) on Lion. There were no validation issues when uploading version 1.1 using XCode's Organiser. This week, I have upgraded to Mountain Lion, and been forced to upgrade to XCode 4.4 as a result. I have changed about 10 lines of code for version 1.1.1. Now when I try to distribute the app, XCode's Organiser fails, with no helpful error message. I tried using Application Loader, which gives me the error: `The app references non-public selectors in Payload/AppName.app/AppName: instance`

From what I've seen around the Internet, this is most probably because I'm using (as it suggests) a private API. But that can't be right, the only code I added was a new `BOOL` and then setting it to `YES` and `NO` a few times.

I need this update out ASAP, as it fixes a nice big flaw to do with the app launching. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As an aside, I reverted my code back to 1.1, then tried to distribute that, and got the exact same error message. Considering they let it upload last week, it seems strange iTunes Connect is now rejecting it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a false-positive on Apple's part. Do you have methods named "instance" in your code? Does changing them to something else solve the problem?

Comment: The closest to that I have is the PayPal SDK has a method called `getInstance` which is used to get the current PayPal Payment object. This has been in the app since day 1 though, unless XCode 4.4 has introduced more stringent API checks.

Comment: It's possible that either there are more stringent checks, or there are new private methods that are disallowed.

Comment: I'd try renaming that method, or you could try to fool the checker by constructing that selector manually with `sel_registerName`.